# Change Sprite array to GameObject array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[EDIT]: [current inspector output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aYiY.png)

I'm beginning with unity and I want to convert this public array of sprites into a public array of gameobjects. How would I do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour, IRecyle 
{

    public Sprite[] sprites;

    public void Restart()
    {
        var renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        renderer.sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)];        
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: In the title of the question you said "change string array to gameObject array". Where are strings involved into this?

Comment: Your question needs a bit more context.  A `GameObject` is a transform + components. You can't turn a `Sprite` into a `GameObject`; what you can do is instantiate `GameObject`s with `SpriteRenderer` components and apply the `Sprites` to them. A single `GameObject` can only have a single `SpriteRenderer`. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I need!

Comment: Basically, in the inspector I need to select 4 separate prefabs of gameobjects instead of sprites (I've attached a picture of what my inspector currently looks like).

Comment: Change public Sprite[] sprites;
 To public SpriteRenderer[] sprites;

Comment: Are you planning to modify/manipulate the SpriteRenderer's internal state from inside your Obstacle class? Because, if not, I think just having the renderers as children of the Obstacle would be enough

Comment: Changing Sprite[] to SpriteRenderer[] gives me error CS0029

Comment: Also, Im not sure what you mean by "internal state" inside the Obstacle class?

Answer (score 0):

if you have prefabs with the sprites you want to use try to change your code:

this:

```
    public Sprite[] sprites;
```

to this:

```
    public GameObject[] spriteGameObjects;`
```

and also this:

```
renderer.sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)];
```

to this:

```
renderer.sprite = spritesGameObjects[Random.Range(0, spritesGameObjects.Length)]
.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
```

I don't have access to Unity right now, so I haven't checked if it's working, but I think it should. 
Kindly let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: I get the following error when I played the code Error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no extension method 'GetComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: Ahh sorry, I missed one ']' character:
change the renderer.sprite = spritesGameObjects[Random.Range(0, spritesGameObjects.Length)
.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite];
to:
renderer.sprite = spritesGameObjects[Random.Range(0, spritesGameObjects.Length)]
.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;

I corrected it in my answer too.